# Oracle dynamic sql, works everywhere but at customers

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic

I have a stored procedure which executes some dynamic sql, shown below. I've tried to cut it down as much as possible so ignore any little errors.

In the office it works, everytime, on `11.2`, `10.2`, `10.1`. At the customers it fails with a message:

```
Unexpected Error

Error Message = "Msg:
MyProc
ORA-06550: line 1, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:

   begin case declare exit for function goto if loop mod null
```

If I capture the dynamic sql that the customer is generating and place it in a variable like below, running on work machines, it works, so it's not that dodgy sql is getting generated. Normally the sql comes from the client so here I've doubled the to_date quotes.

```
mySQL := '
declare 
                pADMINDATE DATE := :1; 
                pEMPLOYEEIDLIKE VARCHAR2(40) := :2; 
                pINCLUDEEMPLOYEE number := :3; 

begin 
BEGIN OTHERPROC.OTHERPROC (1,TO_DATE(''2012-10-03'', ''YYYY-MM-DD''),TO_DATE(''2012-10-03'', ''YYYY-MM-DD''),0); 
END; 
INSERT INTO TP_EMPLOYEES ( 
        ID, 
            EMPLOYEECODE
) 


SELECT ROWNUM, 
       EMPLOYEECODE
FROM ( 

SELECT EMPLOYEECODE
   FROM (SELECT DISTINCT EMPLOYEECODE FROM TP_EEF_TEMP) DISTINCTEMPCODES) A; 
end; ';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    mySQL
    using 
    pADMINDATE,
    pEMPLOYEEIDLIKE,
    pINCLUDEEMPLOYEE;
```

It's not the database version that causes the problem, could it be permissions? It calls another stored procedure within itself which we do regularly in non dynamic sql, could it be that?

At a loss here

Thanks

Comment: *"works everywhere but at customers"* Story of my life.

Comment: @Ben why would it be? It's a special name for a bind variable.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov, I think it was meant to be `:3`; and the OP has just changed it.

Comment: @Ben ) OK then. it would work anyway.

Comment: I'm not certain this is your actual procedure... the column `employee.sexcode` does not exist in your select; yet you're selecting it... You're also ordering by a non-existent column. I would expect this to raise an error so either this is not your actual procedure, which means it's going to be very difficult to debug or your procedure would error in your own environment, which directly contradicts your question.

Comment: ... or the data structures are different. Have you tried comparing the databases?

Comment: I've cut it down a lot, hence the different column names (just corrected). It works and returns the correct data when it hasn't been cut down (well, in work anyway), the full procedure is too big to post fully and is mostly just returning columns. The database schemas are identical.

Comment: `EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEECODE` Qualification of `EMPLOYEECODE`. There is no `Employee` table or alias in your query. Replace `Employee.employeecode` by `DISTINCTEMPCODES.employeecode` or just `employeecode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was carriage returns! Adding this line fixed the problem

```
pQUERY2 := REPLACE(pQUERY, chr(13));
```

A similar problem was highlighted here

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1117462

Thanks for the answers anyway, if anyone knows I would be interested in knowing what setting/patch/whatever makes Oracle sensitive to this, i.e. I tried this on 3 different versions of oracle including the one the customer was on, -but- I didn't patch my 10.2.1 version. 
  Is it something that is fixed in a patch? Is it a setting?

Comment: How is the procedure being run, and where is the dynamic SQL string generated? I'd guess it's more likely to be down to the client application than the database itself, so maybe you're testing it in a different platform rather than version? I'm not sure if it works in your environment with carriage returns, or if you didn't have them in the string you were executing.

Comment: Platform: Windows, client application, ours. Other than the version of Oracle it was all the same

Answer (score 0):

I have found the "works in this server but doesn't work on that server" type of problems before.

Usually it's related to implicit date <-> varchar conversions: since different database servers can have different default formats, it's possible for a statement with an implicit conversion to work in one place and fail in another.

I suggest you to try running your example removing the `pADMINDATE` date variable.

Comment: My understanding is, that Tony's error message shows up when trying to *create* the procedure (rather than running it).